# ModelAdmin: Creating list of records, one per line

Tags: python, django

In my project, I have items grouped by categories. I would like a list of all the items, one item per line, not just those in one category. I want to have multiple views (fieldsets) into this list. It seems I have two options: either do it as a TabularInline (first code block) or do it at the top level with list_display.

The problem with the former is I want to have all categories shown at once. The problem with the latter is there seems, at that level, to be no way to use fieldsets.

I have an admin.py that contains the following:

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item
    extra = 5
    readonly_fields=('myPrice',)
    fields=('name', 'vendor', 'buyer', 'numPackages', 'pkgQuantity', 'pkgPrice', 'myPrice', 'listPrice')

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('CatInfo',  {'fields': ['name'], 'classes': ['collapse']})
        ]
    inlines = [ItemInline]

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

It works fine insofar as I like the ItemInline (and plan to replace the fields with some fieldsets). My problem is that with this, I'm presented with a list of categories and have to click on one and can only edit items in that category. What I want is to be presented with a list of all the items (grouped by category) and edit them directly.

I tried this:

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering=('category',)
    # readonly_fields=('myPrice',)
    list_display_links=('category',)
    list_display=('category', 'name', 'vendor', 'buyer', 'numPackages', 'pkgQuantity', 'pkgPrice', 'myPrice', 'listPrice')
    list_editable=('name', 'vendor', 'buyer', 'numPackages', 'pkgQuantity', 'pkgPrice', 'listPrice')

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

This, as a layout, is close to what I want. But I want to be able to use fieldsets for different sets instead of list_display.

Comment: For me is hard to understand what are you proposing to accomplish. Is this about listing records grouped by categories and be able to edit them?

Comment: I'm porting a spreadsheet to a webapp. This could probably be done easily in a view but as I'm not comfortable with templates and HTML I'm trying to do it in admin. Keeping the idea of a spreadsheet, I want a grid of values, some columns being editable and some readonly, with each row a different item. I also want to see different aspects of the data (one screen showing some fields and another showing others). I thought it could be done with fieldsets, but apparently not.